# C++, Linker Issue returning undefined reference

Tags: c++, reference, linker

This may be a duplicate, but all of the answers to the questions I have seen have not sufficiently answered my question, so I am posting anyways.

My code is as such. Very basic. Copy and pasted from another website.

```
#include <GL/glew.h> // include GLEW and new version of GL on Windows
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // GLFW helper library
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  // start GL context and O/S window using the GLFW helper library
  if (!glfwInit()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // uncomment these lines if on Apple OS X
  /*glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);*/

  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello Triangle", NULL, NULL);
  if (!window) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
    glfwTerminate();
    return 1;
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  // start GLEW extension handler
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  glewInit();

  // get version info
  const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
  const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // version as a string
  printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
  printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

  // tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

  /* OTHER STUFF GOES HERE NEXT */

  // close GL context and any other GLFW resources
  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

I used CodeBlocks. Within the "include" folder I have the directories for these files (GL/GLFW). As you can see they are #included at the top of the code.

However, this returns a long list of "undefined reference" errors. I have seen people mention linkers and offer up a long series of code with no explanation on where to put it. I do not know what linkers are, or rather, I do not know what code I must come up with or where to place it in order for this to work.

A clear explanation and practical assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the list of linker errors and what compiler and OS you are using?   That's the only way we can advise.

Comment: You need to link library during compilation, just including the header will not work. Header just provide the API but library will provide the implementation.

Comment: It isn't just code itself that you need to worry about. The linker is one stage of compilation that is quite a bit after the code phase.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. However, I am still not understanding WHERE I need to put the code. "You need to link library during compilation" - How do I do this? Code:Blocks also doesn't seem to allow me to copy and paste the error output. It's literally just the file path and "undefined reference to 'glfwInit' and undefined reference to 'glfwCreateWindow' and the like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of converting C++ source code into an executable program consists of multiple steps:

- Preprocessing
- Compilation
- Assembling
- Linking

However, normally you just run g++ which then runs different programs that perform one step each. That's why you can specify e.g. the arguments for the linker in the command line for g++, they will simply be passed on the linker.

So, for your problem: You need to link the libraries that contains the symbols (functions, methods etc.) that you want to use. Which libraries and where they are is different to tell without seeing the error messages. But since you're including GL headers, you most likely need to link something like libgl ...

The linker arguments are -L to specify the location (= directory) where the libraries are, and -l for the libraries to link. The 'lib' in the library name as well as the library file suffix (.so, .a) can be omitted, e.g. -lpthread links the library libpthread.so.

Comment: Where would I do this? Would I put this in my code?

Comment: No, you pass the options to g++, e.g.: 'g++ myglprog.cpp -I... -o myglprog -L/usr/local/gl -lgl' -- This is just an example, you have to find the correct library path and file name yourself!

Comment: Thank you for the help Rene. Just one more question. When you link files, do they have to be relative to the location of the project file (cpp, etc) or do they need to be relative to the IDE's install location (for instance, #include GLFW/glfw.h)

Comment: Neither. You specify the path or multiple paths, where the linker should look for the libraries, with the -L argument. There you normally specify an absolute path (like in the example above, /usr/local/ or more likely would be /usr/local/lib). And the name of the library is often to be found in the manual page of the function/class you are using.